# How to prevent Alice to kill a process, but allow Bob to uninstall it?

Tags: windows, access-control-list, kernel

I know Bob who is a system admin. Bob needs to deploy software Foo to Alice's work device based on Windows NT (XP onwards). Foo is security software. It is not malicious.

Alice has local admin permission on her device. Bob wants to disallow Alice to kill a process or uninstall Foo. Bob, however, should be able to uninstall Foo if he wishes to.

Suppose there is a way to prevent local admin Alice to terminate particular process Foo. How can I implement functionality to allow only Bob to uninstall Foo?

Comment: If Alice is a local admin, she has all the same rights on that machine as Bob (whom I assume is a Domain Admin). To get the situation you want, you will have to remove loal admin privileges from Alice's account somehow, which may in turn create other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. No matter what protections you put in place, Alice will always be able to pull her Administrator card and get around them.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that you have is to remove Alice from the Administrators Group, because from personal experience if the domain pushes something to my PC if I don't want it I just disable it through the services or kill the process, although I am not a Domain Administrator I am an admin on every other device on the network.

Comment: If software is a service, there are ways to disable a "Stop" button as well as `net stop servicename` and `sc stop servicename`. There are many ways to prevent local admins to kill a process as well - have a look at modern AV. You won't be able to kill it from process explorer or alike tools. The only way to disable AV is to press a button in its UI to stop it. But if Foo does not provide this UI functionality and uses the same defence mechanisms as modern AV an average Jo won't be able to kill it.

Comment: unfortunately there's always workaround against such protection (generally by taking ownership and resetting permissions on related object, being it registry key or files and folders). A local admin will always have a way, although it could be made more difficult and require some advanced knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't really practical. About as close as you could get is if the vendor modified their service to register as a protected process (Windows 8.1/2012 R2).

Protecting Anti-Malware Services with an Early Launch Anti-Malware (ELAM) driver
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn313124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"In Windows 8.1, a new concept of protected service has been introduced to allow anti-malware user-mode services to be launched as a protected service. After the service is launched as protected, Windows uses code integrity to only allow trusted code to load into the protected service. Windows also protects these processes from code injection and other attacks from admin processes."

[...]
"Updates and servicing

"After the anti-malware service is launched as protected, other non-protected processes (and even admins) aren't able to stop the service. In the case of updates to the service binaries, the anti-malware service needs to receive a callback from the installer to stop itself so that it can be serviced. After the service is stopped, the anti-malware installer can perform upgrades and then follow the steps described above in the Registering the service and Starting the service as protected sections to register the certificate and start the service as protected.

"Note that the service should ensure that only trusted callers can stop the service. Allowing untrusted callers to do so defeats the purpose of protecting the service.

Unregistering the service

"When you uninstall a protected service, the service must mark itself as unprotected by calling the ChangeServiceConfig2 API. Note that because the system doesn't allow any non-protected process to alter the configuration of a protected service, the call to ChangeServiceConfig2 must be made by the protected service itself. After the service has been reconfigured to run as unprotected, the uninstaller can simply take appropriate steps to remove the anti-malware software from the system."